# Объединить списки

Tags: python, list, методы, библиотеки

Есть две библиотеки

```
ОСНОВНОЙ: ['Списки ', '\nПервый список', '\n 4. Пусто', '\n 5. Апельсин', '\n 6. Лимон', '\n 7. 2 мандарина']
ДЛЯ ЗАМЕНЫ: ['Второй список', '\n3. Яблоко ', '\n4. Банан ', '\n5. Груша']
```

Необходимо заменить элементы первого списка элементами из второго

В первом списке номера всегда идут по порядку, во втором такого может не быть.
Если во втором списке есть номер, которого нет в основном, то он должен вставиться сверху или снизу соответственно.

То есть в результате должно получиться:

```
Списки
Первый список
Второй список
3. Яблоко #добавился
4. Банан #заменился
5. Груша #заменился
6. Лимон
7. 2 мандарина
```

Comment: И с чем у вас сложность? Вы же не хотите, чтобы ваше домашнее задание кто-то сделал за вас?

Comment: @CrazyElf Нет, бота делаю. Не понимаю как обратиться к конкретному индексу. Мне нужен хотя бы какой-то набросок

Comment: А переводы строк `\n` куда делись - их нужно чистить из списков?

Comment: @CrazyElf нет, чистить не нужно. Я показал результат с применением `''.join`
 и с выводом в чат (чтобы визуально проще выглядело)

Comment: В общем-то там ничего сложного, но муторно это всё расписывать. Идёте циклами и смотрите...

Comment: @CrazyElf да я пытался. Я пару недель на пайтоне, сложнова-то для меня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не самый эффективный, не самый быстрый, не самый оптимизированный по памяти, но рабочий код:

```
a = ['Списки', 'Первый список', '4. Пусто', '5. Апельсин', '6. Лимон', '7. 2 мандарина']
b = ['Второй список', '3. Яблоко ', '4. Банан ', '5. Груша']
w = []
for i in range(len(a)):     # находим все ненумерованные элементы первого списка, добавляем их в итоговый по порядку
    if a[i][0] not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
        w.append('0. ' + a[i])
    else:
        n = i
        break
for i in range(len(b)):     # находим все ненумерованные элементы второго списка, тоже добавляем их в итоговый по порядку
    if b[i][0] not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
        w.append('0. ' + b[i])
    else:
        m = i
        break
w += a[n:]      # добавляем нумерованные элементы первого списка
for i in range(m, len(b)):      # проводим проверку нумерованных элементов второго списка, делаем необходимое действие(заменяем/добавляем)
    for j in range(len(w)):
        if b[i][:b[i].index('.')] == w[j][:w[j].index('.')]:
            w[j] = b[i]
            break
        elif int(b[i][:b[i].index('.')]) < int(w[j][:w[j].index('.')]):
            w = w[:j] + [b[i]] + w[j:]
            break
k = 0       # красивый вывод
while w[k][0] == '0':
    w[k] = w[k][3:]
    k += 1
print('\n'.join(w))
```

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался

Answer (score 1):

Можно в принципе в три строки сделать. Объединяем два списка с заменой с небольшой заменой-преобразованием строки (убираем `\n` и т.п.).

Фильтруем два раза на список с текстом и числами через `filter()` c lambda-функцией, где проверяем через `isdigit()`, что у нас число в начале строки.

Дальше список с цифровой частью через `split()` делим, конвертируя результат в словарь. Так остаются только уникальные значения.

Список с текстовой частью объединяем со списком, сделанным из словаря.

```
list_1 = ['Списки ', '\nПервый список', '\n 4. Пусто', '\n 5. Апельсин', '\n 6. Лимон', '\n 7. 2 мандарина']
list_2 =  ['Второй список', '\n3. Яблоко ', '\n4. Банан ', '\n5. Груша']

list_combo = [item.replace('\n ', '\n').strip() for item in list_1 + list_2]
list_text = list(filter(lambda x: not x[0].isdigit(), list_combo))
list_nums = dict(r.split('. ') for r in filter(lambda x: x[0].isdigit(), list_combo))

comb = list_text + sorted(['. '.join([k, v]) for k, v in list_nums.items()])
print(*comb, sep='\n')
```